# How to set up a which function in R

Tags: r, function

I am a complete beginner with regards to using R.  I was wondering if anyone could help me set up a which function.  I have the following code:

```
    n_repeats <- 1000
    result <- rep(0, 1000)

    for (i in 1:n_repeats) { 
       sample_population<-rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 1)
       result[i] <- t.test(sample_population)$p.value
    }
```

I wish to use the which function to determine the number of times I observe p values less than 0.1, 0.05 and 0.01

Comment: You don't need the `which` function. You could just use `sum(result < 0.1)`. If you do that `TRUE` is coerced to `1` and `FALSE` to `0`. Thus, the sum gives you the number of values smaller than 0.1.

Answer (score 5):

Another, simple way of doing it is with `replicate` function dedicated for such usages

```
fun <- function() {
  sample_population <- rnorm(n = 20, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  t.test(sample_population)$p.value
}

out <- replicate(1000, fun())

sum(out < 0.1)   # for number of occurrences
mean(out < 0.1)  # for proportion of occurrences
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this example:

```
#reproducibility
set.seed(123)
n_repeats <- 10

#permute
res <- sapply(1:n_repeats,function(i){
  sample_population <- rnorm(n=20,mean=0,sd=1)
  t.test(sample_population)$p.value
}) 

#sample_pvalues
res
#[1] 0.52274134 0.78537647 0.62458875 0.58798328 0.05731831 0.03346176 0.87611218 0.46173318 0.49516940 0.51989789

#which ones are less than 0.1
which(res<0.1)
#[1] 5 6

#Get counts per pvalue groups
table(cut(res,c(0,0.001,0.01,0.1)))
#(0,0.001] (0.001,0.01]   (0.01,0.1] 
#        0            0            2
```

Comment: or even `sum(res<0.1)`

Comment: @zx8754 OP wanted to use `which` to see "the number of times". So you really want `length(which(res<0.1))`

Comment: @Spacedman I understand OP's requirements and hope `table(cut())` answers it. Just wanted to mention there is a function `which()` which does something else.